# Get the first url from list that contains 'posts' in it

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
['http://exampleurl.com/index.php', 'http://exampleurl2.com/in_dex1.php',
 'http://exampleurl.com/posts/images', 'http://exampleurl2.com/posts/tags/etc']
```

How do I get the first url that contains `'posts'`?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct but needs a few changes. You can loop through a list like this:

```
x = ['http://exampleurl.com/index.php', 'http://exampleurl2.com/in_dex1.php', 
     'http://exampleurl.com/posts/images', 'http://exampleurl2.com/posts/tags/etc']
for i in x:
    if 'posts' in i:
        print i
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
next(url for url in urls if 'posts' in url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the list using a list comprehension, then get the first element

```
[url for url in urls if 'posts' in url][0]
```